# How to set radio button 'checked' based on value from database? - React

Tags: reactjs, radio-group

I have a radio button group in a component. I want to set which radio is selected based on it's value taken from the database in an Update/Edit scenario.

```js
export default function updateRadioSelection(){
  const [radioValue, setRadiovalue] = useState("");

  useState(()=>{
    setRadiovalue("pick");    // <-- Assume this value is taken from database, value may be either "delivery" or "pick"
  }, [])

  const changeSelection = (e)=>{
    setRadiovalue(e.target.value);
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="delivery" name="orderType" value="delivery" required onChange={changeSelection} />
      <label htmlFor="delivery">Delivery</label>
      
      <input type="radio" id="pick" name="orderType" value="pick" onChange={changeSelection} />
      <label htmlFor="pick">Pick Up</label>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a `checkbox` or `radio` checked you must use the `checked` prop for the `input` element, it receives a `boolean` value. And you can do something like this

```
export default function updateRadioSelection(){
  const [radioValue, setRadiovalue] = useState("");

  // useState will not execute any kind of callback function, for this case you need to use useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    const dbResult = getRadioFromDb();
    setRadiovalue(dbResult);
  }, [])

  const changeSelection = (e)=>{
    setRadiovalue(e.target.value);
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="delivery" name="orderType" value="delivery" required onChange={changeSelection} checked={radioValue === 'delivery'} />
      <label htmlFor="delivery">Delivery</label>
      
      <input type="radio" id="pick" name="orderType" value="pick" onChange={changeSelection} checked={radioValue === 'pick'} />
      <label htmlFor="pick">Pick Up</label>
    </div>
  )
}
```

You can read more about radio input in its [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/radio)

Answer (score 0):

Just a few minutes after posting this question I found the answer I was searching for. Turns out it's pretty easy.

Just add `checked={radioValue === "pick"}` for the `Pick Up` radio button & the same for other radio button by replacing `"pick"` with `"delivery"`

reference - [react.tips/radio-buttons-in-reactjs](http://react.tips/radio-buttons-in-reactjs/#:~:text=%22option1%22-,checked%3D%7Bthis.state.selectedOption%20%3D%3D%3D%20%27option1%27%7D,-/%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Option%201)